# Swagger does not working well with Play Framework 2

Tags: scala, swagger, playframework-2.2

I working on RESTful API using Play Framework 2.2.1(Java). I using IDEA and I want to add Swagger to my project.

So, first I created `project/Build.scala' file, because project by default doesn't have it. Here its contents:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "speeder"
  val appVersion = "0.1-beta"

  val appDependencies: Seq[sbt.ModuleID] = Seq(
    "com.wordnik" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.3-SNAPSHOT",
    "com.wordnik" %% "swagger-play2-utils" % "1.3-SNAPSHOT"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    resolvers := Seq(
      "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository",
      "sonatype-snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
      "sonatype-releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases",
      "java-net" at "http://download.java.net/maven/2",
      "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"))
}
```

IDEA has recognized it and suggested to import project, what I did. I've annotate my controller like this:

```
@Api(value = "/accounts", description = "Operation with accounts")
public class Accounts extends BaseController {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Create user", notes = "This can only be done by the logged in user.", httpMethod = "POST")
    @ApiImplicitParams(@ApiImplicitParam(name = "body", value = "Created user object", required = true, dataType = "User", paramType = "body"))
    public static Result signup() { //... }
}
```

I've also added the route for API documentation:

```
GET         /api-docs.json        controllers.ApiHelpController.getResources
```

Then I ran the `play dependencies` from the console and restart the server. So now I opening `http://localhost:9000/api-docs.json`, and I see this:

```
{"apiVersion":"0.2","swaggerVersion":"1.2","apis":[{"path":"/accounts","description":"Operation with accounts"}]}
```

As you can note, there is no information about annotated method, it's only about class. And my IDEA doesn't see `com.wordnik.swagger.annotations` package or `controllers.ApiHelpController.getResources` controller. The app is still compilable.

So what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use this lib https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger

This library takes a different approach than annotation (which force you into learning a new API), you write swagger spec directly in your routes file as comments. It automatically generates parameters definition based on routes file

Answer (score 0):

Your settings are rigth if you get that JSON, finally you need to add more things to inform like the other api methods.

Then go to this page

http://swagger.wordnik.com/

and copy your.server:9000/api-docs.json, in the green area at the beginning then go and you have the well documented api, then you can make that page in your own play app

Comment: I've already tried, but JSON has no information about methods, so I got an empty category.

Comment: Maybe the only thing that you must do is exit from play console, start again compile and then try again, this works for me

Answer (score 0):

You might need the 1.3.9-SNAPSHOT. Also you might need to specify

```
api.version="1.0"
swagger.api.basepath="http://localhost:9000"
```

in your application.conf

Answer (score 0):

On http://localhost:9000/api-docs.json
which outputs a path /accounts

You can find method informations in here
http://localhost:9000/api-docs.json/accounts